# Delete request only responded with 404 not found

Tags: node.js, express

i'm building a Rest API with node js and express the delete request is only responding with 404 not found

get and post requests are working fine and i'm connected to the data base

```
app.delete('deletetodo/:id',(req, res) =>{
    let id = req.params.id
    if(!ObjectID.isValid(id))
        return res.status(404).send()
    Todo.findOneAndDelete(id).then((todo) =>{
        if(!todo)
             return res.status(404).send()
        res.send(todo)
    }, (e) =>{
        res.status(404).send()
    })
})
```

it always respond with 404 with this html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>Cannot DELETE /deletetodo/5d4a2eb23a43350c60ff7c4d</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

i tested that piece of code in a separate file and it word fine i think the problem is with the delete request itself

Comment: I think you should try `then((err, todo) =>{` instead of just todo.

Comment: try `app.delete('/deletetodo/:id', ` , you are missing the '/' from the beggining of the request, and thats why it does not find the route

Comment: Loool i'm that blind thank you so much i'v been banging my head for a couple of days

Answer (score 2):

The fix is to add a '/' prefixed before the deletetodo route as shown below.

**Before**

```
app.delete('deletetodo/:id',(req, res) =>{
```

**After with slash pre-fixed to the route**

```
app.delete('/deletetodo/:id',(req, res) =>{
```

In case others are trying to diagnose if this is the same issue that affects them, you'll know something is wrong if you get an unexpected 404 for a known route and the route was never called in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should observe this statement

```
if(!ObjectID.isValid(id))
        return res.status(404).send()
```

For being sure you can try by removing the statement also.

So your code should look like

```
app.delete('deletetodo/:id',(req, res) =>{
    let id = req.params.id
    Todo.findOneAndDelete(id).then((todo) =>{
        if(!todo)
             return res.status(404).send()
        res.send(todo)
    }, (e) =>{
        res.status(404).send()
    })
})
```

Comment: still the same thing